# Best practices for making code string safe for database & output

Tags: php, security, validation

I am currently working on a project that saves code snippets to a database, which can be viewed and copied later. I just wanted to know the best way to check the input would be safe from SQL injection and XSS, CSRF on the client side when viewed.

I know the string will have to be converted, but in not sure which is the best method.

Any links or examples would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Wow there are probably 599 posts exaxtly like this on SO.

Answer (score 0):

XSS: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php
SQLI: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php
CSRF: you should generate token or at least check referrer.

In addition, valid the input type, i.e if its suppose to be numeric value, use intval($input), and so on.

Comment: thanks will read up on that. When the client would like to copy it, would I have to convert it back?

Comment: no, it will look the same in the browser, its just escaping in the database and in the page source. like &gt; instead of > and etc...

Comment: I downvoted. `mysql_real_escape_string()` is not as good as using prepared statements, which makes the whole escaping problem obsolete (and not just for MySQL special charaters. Plus, not everyone uses MySQL). Use PDO and prepared statements, or a well-developed third-party database abstract layer. There are XSS opportunities for HTMLSpecialchar'd text, too, by fiddling with character encodings and the like. See http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/dec/google-xss-example for an example.